# Парсинг std::string

Tags: c++, строки

Цель: проверка строки на числа.

Требуется вводить строку до тех пор, пока в ней не будут исключительно числа. Ранее был реализован перебор всех элементов char массива(проверяется каждый элемент по таблице ASCII). Как в такой ситуации быть с std::string? Возможно есть более простые методы. Буду признателен за помощь.

Код, использованный раннее:

```
  bool CheckingNumber(char* destination) {
    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(destination) - 1; i++) {
        if (destination[i] < 48 || destination[i] > 57) { return false; break; }
        else { return true; }
    }
    return {  };
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В чем проблема? Убедиться, что есть не цифра? Тогда можно, например, так.

```
bool CheckingNumber(const string& destination) {
    return s.find_first_not_of("0123456789") == s.npos;
}
```

В принципе, можно через регулярные выражения, но это из пушки по воробьям...

Кстати, ваш код тоже можно упростить:

```
bool CheckingNumber(char* destination) {
    return strspn(destination,"0123456789") == strlen(destination);
}
```